# AWS Java SDK on JBoss AS7 - module.xml entries

Tags: maven, amazon-web-services, jboss, jboss7.x, java-ee-6

I am having problems using the new AmazonAWS SDK in a JBoss AS 7.1 (EE6) project

I am just using the S3 library, so in accordance with the new release (1.9.7) I am only using the s3, core, kms jars

```
-aws-java-sdk-core-1.9.17.jar
-aws-java-sdk-s3-1.9.17.jar
-aws-java-sdk-kms-1.9.17.jar
```

So I have created 3 separate module.xml entries for each jar within the /com/amazonaws directory:

/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-s3/main/module.xml

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.amazonaws.aws-java-sdk-s3">
    <properties>
        <property name="jboss.api" value="private"/>
    </properties>

    <resources>
        <resource-root path="aws-java-sdk-s3-1.9.17.jar"/>
        <!-- Insert resources here -->
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="com.amazonaws.aws-java-sdk-core" />
        <module name="com.amazonaws.aws-java-sdk-kms" />
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-kms/main/module.xml

```
<resources>
    <resource-root path="aws-java-sdk-kms-1.9.17.jar"/>
    <!-- Insert resources here -->
</resources>

<dependencies>
    <module name="com.amazonaws.aws-java-sdk-core" />
</dependencies>
```

/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-core/main/module.xml

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.amazonaws.aws-java-sdk-core">
    <properties>
        <property name="jboss.api" value="private"/>
    </properties>

    <resources>
        <resource-root path="aws-java-sdk-core-1.9.17.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="commons-logging-1.1.3.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="httpclient-4.3.4.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jackson-databind-2.3.2.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="joda-time-2.2.jar"/>

        <!-- Insert resources here -->
    </resources>

</module>
```

(I have put the extra dependencies eg. apache-commons, jodatime etc. directly in the module directory)

The following jboss-deployment-structure.xml entry:

```
  <sub-deployment name="Processor-ejb.jar">
    <dependencies>
        <module name="com.amazonaws.aws-java-sdk-core" />
        <module name="com.amazonaws.aws-java-sdk-s3" />
        <module name="com.amazonaws.aws-java-sdk-kms" />

    </dependencies>
  </sub-deployment>
```

(I have also tried declaring these as EAR-level dependancies with export=true)

The the following pom.xml entry:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.17</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

But whenever I try to initialise a new S3 client:

```
AWSCredentials credentials = new ProfileCredentialsProvider("ProcessingApp").getCredentials();
AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
```

I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/management/MalformedObjectNameException
    at com.amazonaws.jmx.SdkMBeanRegistrySupport.registerMetricAdminMBean(SdkMBeanRegistrySupport.java:27)
    at com.amazonaws.metrics.AwsSdkMetrics.registerMetricAdminMBean(AwsSdkMetrics.java:330)
    at com.amazonaws.metrics.AwsSdkMetrics.<clinit>(AwsSdkMetrics.java:308)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<clinit>(AmazonS3Client.java:261)
    at net.processor.actions.scheduled.ScheduledActionsBean.minuteActions(ScheduledActionsBean.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:374) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.EJBInvocationContext.proceed(EJBInvocationContext.java:44)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:56)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.Interceptor.aroundTimeout(Interceptor.java:201)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:74)
    at org.jboss.seam.core.BijectionInterceptor.aroundInvoke(BijectionInterceptor.java:79)
    ... 56 more
```

My hunch would be a conflict with apache-commons-logging as there is an import in the SdkMBeanRegistrySupport class and I know JBoss uses this library elsewhere using an alias to org.slf4j.jcl-over-slf4j, but I thought that putting the apache lib in with the jar would sort this out?

I am fairly new to AS7 so maybe I'm missing a trick?

Comment: Try add `<module name="javax.api"/>` as dependency  in *com.amazonaws.aws-java-sdk-core* `module.xml`

Comment: Yes, you're right, that got me past that exception and on the right path...thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got eventually thanks to @Federico Sierra, here is the sdk-core module.xml (nb. I had to drop the commons-logging, httpclient and httpcore jars into the module folder as the ones shipped with JBoss arent compatible, I added the jackson and joda libs as their own modules)...

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.amazonaws.aws-java-sdk-core">
    <properties>
        <property name="jboss.api" value="private"/>
    </properties>

    <resources>
        <resource-root path="aws-java-sdk-core-1.9.17.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="commons-logging-1.1.3.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="httpclient-4.3.4.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="httpcore-4.3.2.jar"/>
        <!-- Insert resources here -->
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.xml.stream.api"/>
        <module name="javax.xml.bind.api"/>
        <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson"/>
        <module name="org.joda.time"/>
    </dependencies>

</module>
```

and the sdk-s3 module.xml needed javax.xml.stream.api too

```
<resources>
    <resource-root path="aws-java-sdk-s3-1.9.17.jar"/>
    <!-- Insert resources here -->
</resources>

<dependencies>
    <module name="com.amazonaws.aws-java-sdk-core" />
    <module name="com.amazonaws.aws-java-sdk-kms" />
    <module name="javax.xml.stream.api"/>
</dependencies>
```

Hope this helps someone else

Comment: Thank you so much, I actually created a maven assembly descriptor for that. Maybe this helps someone: https://github.com/Sweazer/jgroups-native-s3-ping/blob/master/src/main/assembly/module-assembly.xml

Comment: oh nice project! does it work with JBoss AS7.2? or just Wildfly?

Comment: I only tested it with Wildfly, but I don't see any reason for it not to work. The module urn version might be different on AS7.2 but apart from that, it should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

I want to share my code, it is working to me, I hope that it be useful to you

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.5" name="com.amazonaws.aws-java-sdk-s3">
    <properties>
        <property name="jboss.api" value="private"/>
    </properties>

    <resources>
        <resource-root path="aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.106.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.106.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="aws-java-sdk-kms-1.11.106.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jmespath-java-1.11.106.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="commons-logging-1.1.1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="httpclient-4.5.2.redhat-1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="httpcore-4.4.4.redhat-1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jackson-annotations-2.8.9.redhat-1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jackson-databind-2.8.9.redhat-1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jackson-core-2.8.9.redhat-1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jackson-dataformat-cbor-2.6.6.jar"/>
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.xml.bind.api"/>
        <module name="javax.xml.stream.api"/>
        <module name="org.joda.time"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

I use only a folder "com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-s3" in the jboss y there I put all the jars.

Comment: Could you please tell me how does your pom.xml look like? because I still cant get my code to load the modules..